# splitting the multiline string into a format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

I am trying to split the multiline string into an format

I tried with the solutions in this link https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp but not worked

Answer (score 1):

```
lines = [line for line in txt.splitlines() if line]

for idx in range(0, len(lines), 2):
  keys = lines[idx].split() 
  values = lines[idx+1].split()
  for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    print(f"{k}:{v}")
```

Output:

```
1.name:chandu
2.address:madhuranagr
3.option:234
4a.option1:345
4b.option2:456
4c.option3:789
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
# Gets an array where each entry is a line.
lines = txt.split('\n')
# Discard first and last lines, which are empty.
lines = lines[1:-1]

# Iterate over pairs of lines.
for i in range(len(lines)//2):
  # Compute indices for the relevant lines
  question_index = 2*i
  answer_index = 2*i + 1

  # Split the entries in a line, using strip() to remove the last (empty) entry.
  question_parts = lines[question_index].strip().split(' ')
  answer_parts = lines[answer_index].strip().split(' ')

  # Print question-answer pairs.
  for j in range(len(question_parts)):
    # Skip questions without answers.
    if j < len(answer_parts):
      print('%s:%s' % (question_parts[j], answer_parts[j]))
```

It solves for that particular example, but it does not deal with all the edge cases: for instance, is it possible that one of the middle answers is missing? If so, how is the data structured in that case?

Comment: I think you need to better specify the input format. For instance, what happens if instead of the line "345 456 789" you had only "456"? How would I know what question that answers refers to? It's ambiguous whether it'd be answering 4a.option1, 4b.option2, 4c.option3 or 4d.option4, even if you include spaces before and after, like "      456     ".